# Count frequency of categories in column across subsets of data

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataset that looks like this:

```
         Date Plot  Plant Number Growth Class 2
0  2021-06-14   T2            13              I
1  2021-06-14   C2             6              I
2  2021-06-14   C2             3              S
3  2021-06-14   T1             1              S
4  2021-06-14   C1            18              I
5  2021-06-14   C1            22              S
6  2021-06-14   C3             5              V
7  2021-06-14   C4            15             SS
8  2021-06-14   C1             7              V
9  2021-06-14   C4             1              V
10 2021-06-20   C3            21              S
11 2021-06-20   T2            23              V
12 2021-06-20   C4             5              I
13 2021-06-20   T4            23              V
14 2021-06-28   C4            15             SS
15 2021-06-28   C1            21              V
16 2021-06-28   T4            25              I
17 2021-06-28   T1            17              V
18 2021-07-05   T2            19              V
19 2021-07-05   T4            11              I
```

I want to know value counts for the categories in the column "Growth Class 2", but across each date and plot, preferably with a single table.

I've tried pivoting the dataframe in various ways and using the value_counts method, but haven't had any success.

I can create slices of the dataframe using boolean masking, then use the value_counts method, but it is laborious and I'm looking for a better way that preferably results in a table of values across all dates and plots for easy comparison.

```
# Can do it for each plot and date individually, but there has to be better way.
mask1 = df['Date'] == '2021-06-14'
mask2 = df['Plot'] == 'C2'
df[mask1 & mask2]['Growth Class 2'].value_counts()

Out[126]: 
I     1
S     1
SS    0
V     0
Name: Growth Class 2, dtype: int64
```

Thank you for reading.

Comment: you may want to look into `groupby`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you're looking for [`pd.crosstab`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.crosstab.html):

```
>>> pd.crosstab(index=df["Growth Class 2"], columns=[df.Date, df.Plot])

Date         2021-06-14                2021-06-20          2021-06-28          2021-07-05
Plot                 C1 C2 C3 C4 T1 T2         C3 C4 T2 T4         C1 C4 T1 T4         T2 T4
GrowthClass2
I                     1  1  0  0  0  1          0  1  0  0          0  0  0  1          0  1
S                     1  1  0  0  1  0          1  0  0  0          0  0  0  0          0  0
SS                    0  0  0  1  0  0          0  0  0  0          0  1  0  0          0  0
V                     1  0  1  1  0  0          0  0  1  1          1  0  1  0          1  0
```

Answer (score 1):

You can group by `Date` and `Plot` first using [`.groupby()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) before using `value_counts()`:

```
df.groupby(['Date', 'Plot'])['Growth Class 2'].value_counts()
```

Result:

```
Date        Plot  Growth Class 2
2021-06-14  C1    I                 1
                  S                 1
                  V                 1
            C2    I                 1
                  S                 1
            C3    V                 1
            C4    SS                1
                  V                 1
            T1    S                 1
            T2    I                 1
2021-06-20  C3    S                 1
            C4    I                 1
            T2    V                 1
            T4    V                 1
2021-06-28  C1    V                 1
            C4    SS                1
            T1    V                 1
            T4    I                 1
2021-07-05  T2    V                 1
            T4    I                 1
Name: Growth Class 2, dtype: int64
```